# hp-ux how to get 2 hours ago bash datetime

Tags: date, hp-ux

we are using hp-ux servers
we need to get 2 hours ago datetime value in bash shell script ?

how can i do that any experiences ?

Answer (score 7):

```
date -d -2hours; date --version
```

Thu Apr 14 02:38:08 CEST 2011
date (GNU coreutils) 7.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a shell script expert, but you may want to check this site at [unix.com](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/31944-simple-date-time-calulation-bash.html). They provide this example for subtracting from dates:

```
   # subtract from any date
    date --date "$dte 3 days 5 hours 10 sec ago"
    date --date "$dte -3 days -5 hours -10 sec"
```